# Binary tree not inserting

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm working on a binary tree program and when calling my insert function it appears to insert the value being entered, and when checking for that value I get nothing and am stumped right now what could I be missing or what could be wrong? I've provided the class data, and the insert/search function definitions below, I just have odd feeling this has to do with my implementation of templates or just templates in general help?

```
struct node
{
 string keyValue; //value to stored that is being searched for in our tree
 node *left; //left side of pointing tree from parent node
 node *right; //right side of pointing tree from parent node

};
template <class T> 
class Tree
{
  public: 
   Tree(); //constructor
  ~Tree(); //destructor

void displayTree();     
void insertTree(T key);
node *searchTree(T key);
void deleteTree();

private:

 node *root; //points to the root point of our tree
 void displayTree(node *leaf);
 void insertTree(T key, node *leaf); //takes in our keyValue to 
 void deleteTree(node*leaf);
 node *search(T key, node *leaf);
};

 template <class T>
 void Tree<T>::insertTree(T key)
 {
  cout << "instert1" << endl;
   if(root != NULL)
   {
    cout << "instert2" << endl;
    insertTree(key, root);
   }
   else
   {
    cout << "inster else..." << endl;
    root = new node;
    root->keyValue = key;
    cout << root->keyValue << "--root key value" << endl;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
 }   

}

template <class T>      
void Tree<T>::insertTree(T key, node *leaf)
{
 if(key < leaf->keyValue)
 {
   if(leaf->left != NULL)
   { 
    insertTree(key, leaf->left); 
   }
   else //descend tree to find appropriate NULL node to store keyValue (left side of tree)
   {

     leaf->left = new node; //Creating new node to store our keyValue (data)
     leaf->left -> keyValue = key;
     leaf->left -> left = NULL; //Assigning left and right child of current child node to NULL
     leaf->left -> right = NULL;
   }
  }
   else if(key >= leaf->keyValue)
   {
     if(leaf->right != NULL)
     {
      insertTree(key, leaf->right);
     }
     else //descend tree to find appropriate NULL node to store keyValue (right side of tree)
     {
      leaf->right = new node; //Creating new node to store our keyValue (data)
      leaf->right -> keyValue = key;
      leaf->right -> right = NULL; //Assigning left and right child of current child node to NULL
      leaf->right -> left = NULL;
    }
  }     
}
    template <class T>
node *Tree<T>::searchTree(T key)
{
 cout << "searching for...key: " << key << " and given root value:" << endl;
  return search(key, root);
}
template <class T>
node *Tree<T>::search(T key, node*leaf)
{
  if(leaf != NULL)
  {
    cout << "check passed for search!" << endl;
    if(key == leaf->keyValue)
    {
       return leaf;
    }
    if(key < leaf->keyValue)
    {
      return search(key, leaf->left);
    }
    else
    {
      return search(key, leaf->right);
    }

  }

  else 
  {
    cout << key << " Not found...!" << endl;
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

Comment: In side your insert function, you try to assign `T key` to `string leaf->left->key`. There may not be a valid conversion. I think it's better to make Node a template class too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work. You can look here: http://ideone.com/w9Aa1w

What you may need to do, which is what I did, is templatize your node struct, like so...

```
template <typename T>
struct NodeStruct
{
 T keyValue; //value to stored that is being searched for in our tree
 NodeStruct<T> *left; //left side of pointing tree from parent node
 NodeStruct<T> *right; //right side of pointing tree from parent node
};
```

Then in your tree class typedef your new node type as just 'node':

```
typedef NodeStruct<T> node;
```

It seemed to insert properly though.

In the future it would help if you are more clear with the exact problem you are having, and instead of just posting a whole program, determine at least a subsection of code you are having a problem with.

This question is too vague and probably won't be helpful to anybody else as reference material.